# Clone partition table of a dying hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, backup, clonezilla, disk-image

I have a hard disk here that looks like it is dying sooner or later. SMART checks already give me a lot of errors. The system is a dual boot with Windows and Linux and (not quite sure about that actually) maybe also some recovery partition and therefore several partitions.

I tried to make an image of the whole disk using clonezilla but this fails due to some read errors in one partition where clonezilla repeatedly tries to read same sector over and over even if I tell clonezilla to ignore errors. I aborted the imaging process after getting the error always for the same sector for several hours.

As the corrupted partition is the Linux `/home` partition I have a backup of all the data which I could restore manually. Also all other partitions can also be imaged without errors hence I could restore all the other partitions from image. Is there a possibility -- either an option of clonezilla or a different tool -- that can clone the partition table and maybe selected partitions to another disk? Or is there any other way I didn't think of?

Comment: Try looking at this. http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm

Comment: You can use `ddrescue` (a version of dd which can deal/ (Skip) bad sectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While searching through the package repository of my linux distro, I came across a tool similar to ddrescue. It's called myrescue and tries to avoid broken sectors and first read all the still good ones.

It did a real good job and I could rescue the whole disk but some 15 sectors or so.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the grc.com spinrite program.  It has an option to scan the entire disk and attempts to fix (by re-recording/refreshing) disk sectors.   I have done this in the past to a failing disk to get it operable enough to at least make a good backup while I had the time.